# Heroku pg:backups restore fail due apparently to Rails application timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I've run into an issue with restoring my database on Heroku. I have restored the database multiple times using `pg:pull` as well as the `pg:backups restore` method. But with a recent increase in db size, it is not working.  I note that restoring from one local machine to another using a dump file DOES work.  But it doesn't work on Heroku.

My specs:

1. Rails 4.2, Ruby 2.2.0, Postgres 9.4.1
2. Production db hosted using Heroku's 'Standard 0' Postgres service ($50/month).
3. 2x web dyno, 1x worker
4. Unicorn server

To give you a sense of my database size, prior to this latest restore, there were 83 tables, around 10mm rows, and the dump file size is around 350MB.

I use my local database to collect large data sets.  Periodically, I will use pg_restore to replace this data to production on Heroku.

I recently downloaded a lot of data to my local database for one of the tables which I will call `rankings`.  This table has increased from 7mm rows to 60mm rows.  The pg_dump file is now 1.24GB.

Per usual, I did the following to transfer this new database to heroku:

1. `pg_dump`
2. uploaded file to aws s3
3. `heroku pg:backups restore AWS_FILE_URL HEROKU_DATABASE_URL`

It keeps failing with the following message (from `heroku pg:backups info r023`):

```
//after successfully restoring all tables and data prior to this://    
2015-08-09 19:37:33 +0000: pg_restore: processing data for table "rankings"
2015-08-09 19:41:49 +0000: 2015/08/09 19:41:49 aborting: could not write to output stream: Expected HTTP Status 206 or 200, received: "403 Forbidden"
2015-08-09 19:41:49 +0000: waiting for restore to complete
2015-08-09 19:41:49 +0000: pg_restore: [custom archiver] could not read from input file: end of file
2015-08-09 19:41:49 +0000: restore done
2015-08-09 19:41:49 +0000: waiting for download to complete
2015-08-09 19:41:49 +0000: download done
```

[Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgres-logs-errors#log-could-not-receive-data-from-client-connection-reset-by-peer) points out that this is a timeout from the application, not the database.

I note, however, that after many tries this timeout occurs only when the data for the newly updated `rankings` table is being processed.

I read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13004664/why-is-rails-dropping-the-postgres-connection-on-large-bulk-inserts) that maybe it was a timeout from unicorn.  But I have set my unicorn timeout to 18000 seconds.

I am stumped and could use some guidance.

Below is output from logs:

```
    015-08-09T17:52:34Z app[postgres.11]: [GREEN] checkpoint starting: xlog
    2015-08-09T17:52:39Z app[postgres.11]: [GREEN] checkpoint complete: wrote 53 buffers (0.2%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 40 recycled; write=1.105 s, sync=4.111 s, total=5.224 s; sync files=3, longest=4.048 s, average=1.370 s
    2015-08-09T17:52:43.777815+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 dyno=heroku.22448404.22d13b5c-8725-43f4-9f0b-1b8e219825a9 sample#load_avg_1m=0.00 sample#load_avg_5m=0.00 sample#load_avg_15m=0.01
    2015-08-09T17:52:43.777815+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 dyno=heroku.22448404.22d13b5c-8725-43f4-9f0b-1b8e219825a9 sample#memory_total=546.99MB sample#memory_rss=529.55MB sample#memory_cache=2.30MB sample#memory_swap=15.13MB sample#memory_pgpgin=152151pages sample#memory_pgpgout=15996pages
    2015-08-09T17:52:31+00:00 app[heroku-postgres]: source=HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GREEN sample#current_transaction=366264 sample#db_size=3561754388bytes sample#tables=83 sample#active-connections=6 sample#waiting-connections=0 sample#index-cache-hit-rate=0 sample#table-cache-hit-rate=0.66952 sample#load-avg-1m=1.245 sample#load-avg-5m=0.845 sample#load-avg-15m=0.62 sample#read-iops=1.2 sample#write-iops=2554.6 sample#memory-total=15405668kB sample#memory-free=171092kB sample#memory-cached=14145576kB sample#memory-postgres=490544kB
    2015-08-09T17:52:46Z app[postgres.11021]: [GREEN] canceling statement due to user request
    Query: COPY rankings (id, person_id, max, min, current, date, period_years_min_max, created_at, updated_at) FROM stdin;
    2015-08-09T17:52:46Z app[postgres.11021]: [GREEN] could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
    2015-08-09T17:52:46Z app[postgres.11021]: [GREEN] incomplete message from client
```

below is the full output from heroku logs -t:

```
015-08-10T02:55:04Z app[postgres.3977]: [GREEN] statement: DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE 
2015-08-10T02:55:05Z app[postgres.3675]: [GREEN] canceling autovacuum task 
2015-08-10T02:55:05Z app[postgres.3977]: [GREEN] sending cancel to blocking autovacuum PID 3675 
Detail: Process 3977 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 35169 of database 16385. 
Query: DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE 
2015-08-10T02:55:05Z app[postgres.3977]: [GREEN] process 3977 still waiting for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 35169 of database 16385 after 1000.367 ms 
Detail: Process holding the lock: 3675. Wait queue: 3977. 
Query: DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE 
2015-08-10T02:55:05Z app[postgres.3977]: [GREEN] process 3977 acquired AccessExclusiveLock on relation 35169 of database 16385 after 1000.779 ms 
Query: DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE 
2015-08-10T02:55:05Z app[postgres.3977]: [GREEN] drop cascades to 97 other objects 
Detail: drop cascades to extension hstore 
drop cascades to type daily_box_input 
//<--84 tables, materialized views and views redacted for brevity-->// 
drop cascades to table users 
drop cascades to extension pg_stat_statements 
2015-08-10T02:55:05Z app[postgres.3977]: [GREEN] statement: CREATE SCHEMA public 
2015-08-10T02:55:05Z app[postgres.3977]: [GREEN] statement: ALTER SCHEMA public OWNER TO uca46vrebkj2l9 
2015-08-10T02:54:33+00:00 app[heroku-postgres]: source=HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GREEN sample#current_transaction=368590 sample#db_size=4203753236bytes sample#tables=83 sample#active-connections=3 sample#waiting-connections=0 sample#index-cache-hit-rate=0 sample#table-cache-hit-rate=0.66674 sample#load-avg-1m=0.45 sample#load-avg-5m=0.71 sample#load-avg-15m=0.66 sample#read-iops=17.058 sample#write-iops=498.2 sample#memory-total=15405668kB sample#memory-free=283204kB sample#memory-cached=14065608kB sample#memory-postgres=477864kB 
2015-08-10T02:55:57.359270+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H80 desc="Maintenance mode" method=GET path="/" host=www.studiocomps.com request_id=e0d6bbd7-076f-4a56-93a1-2f80a45d28c4 fwd="74.86.158.110" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
2015-08-10T02:56:02Z app[postgres.4009]: [GREEN] statement: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_stat_statements 
2015-08-10T02:56:03.118589+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H80 desc="Maintenance mode" method=GET path="/" host=test.studiocomps.com request_id=25fbbab0-8005-454c-b432-0f9b91cd5a75 fwd="69.64.56.47" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
2015-08-10T02:55:43+00:00 app[heroku-postgres]: source=HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GREEN sample#current_transaction=368608 sample#db_size=9137940bytes sample#tables=0 sample#active-connections=2 sample#waiting-connections=0 sample#index-cache-hit-rate=0 sample#table-cache-hit-rate=0 sample#load-avg-1m=0.625 sample#load-avg-5m=0.7 sample#load-avg-15m=0.66 sample#read-iops=234.98 sample#write-iops=226.24 sample#memory-total=15405668kB sample#memory-free=4200392kB sample#memory-cached=10112136kB sample#memory-postgres=470496kB
```

and the tail end output from heroku logs -t --ps postgres:

```
2015-08-10T02:46:35Z app[postgres.2427]: [GREEN] duration: 3538.409 ms statement: COPY flows (id, created_at, updated_at, medium_id, value_subunit, timing_id, ultimate_ratio_id, sheet_id, company_id, value_to_date_subunit, period_start, period_end, currency_code, local_title, kind_id, theaters, screens, flowable_id, flowable_type) FROM stdin;
2015-08-10T02:47:15Z app[postgres.11]: [GREEN] checkpoint starting: xlog 
2015-08-10T02:47:53Z app[postgres.11]: [GREEN] checkpoint complete: wrote 14930 buffers (47.8%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 55 recycled; write=30.562 s, sync=7.386 s, total=38.138 s; sync files=219, longest=5.843 s, average=0.033 s 
2015-08-10T02:47:57Z app[postgres.2829]: [GREEN] statement: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_stat_statements 
2015-08-10T02:48:13Z app[postgres.11]: [GREEN] checkpoint starting: xlog 
2015-08-10T02:48:42Z app[postgres.11]: [GREEN] checkpoint complete: wrote 3766 buffers (12.1%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 38 recycled; write=26.669 s, sync=1.943 s, total=28.658 s; sync files=36, longest=1.118 s, average=0.053 s 
2015-08-10T02:49:11Z app[postgres.11]: [GREEN] checkpoint starting: xlog 
2015-08-10T02:49:25Z app[postgres.11]: [GREEN] checkpoint complete: wrote 80 buffers (0.3%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 26 recycled; write=2.021 s, sync=11.500 s, total=13.529 s; sync files=3, longest=6.301 s, average=3.833 s 
2015-08-10T02:50:15Z app[postgres.11]: [GREEN] checkpoint starting: xlog 
2015-08-10T02:50:20Z app[postgres.11]: [GREEN] checkpoint complete: wrote 81 buffers (0.3%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 38 recycled; write=1.586 s, sync=3.825 s, total=5.477 s; sync files=2, longest=3.823 s, average=1.912 s 
2015-08-10T02:51:08Z app[postgres.2427]: [GREEN] canceling statement due to user request 
Query: COPY rankings (id, person_id, max, min, current, date, period_years_min_max, created_at, updated_at) FROM stdin; 
2015-08-10T02:51:08Z app[postgres.2427]: [GREEN] could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer 
2015-08-10T02:51:08Z app[postgres.2427]: [GREEN] incomplete message from client 
2015-08-10T02:51:27Z app[postgres.11]: [GREEN] checkpoint starting: xlog 
2015-08-10T02:54:17Z app[postgres.11]: [GREEN] checkpoint complete: wrote 2098 buffers (6.7%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 58 recycled; write=169.538 s, sync=0.952 s, total=170.500 s; sync files=11, longest=0.887 s, average=0.086 s 
2015-08-10T02:55:04Z app[postgres.3977]: [GREEN] statement: DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE 
2015-08-10T02:55:05Z app[postgres.3675]: [GREEN] canceling autovacuum task 
2015-08-10T02:55:05Z app[postgres.3977]: [GREEN] sending cancel to blocking autovacuum PID 3675 
Detail: Process 3977 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 35169 of database 16385. 
Query: DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE 
2015-08-10T02:55:05Z app[postgres.3977]: [GREEN] process 3977 still waiting for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 35169 of database 16385 after 1000.367 ms 
Detail: Process holding the lock: 3675. Wait queue: 3977. 
Query: DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE 
2015-08-10T02:55:05Z app[postgres.3977]: [GREEN] process 3977 acquired AccessExclusiveLock on relation 35169 of database 16385 after 1000.779 ms 
Query: DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE 
2015-08-10T02:55:05Z app[postgres.3977]: [GREEN] drop cascades to 97 other objects 
Detail: drop cascades to extension hstore 
drop cascades to type daily_box_input 
//<--84 tables, materialized views and views redacted for brevity-->// 
drop cascades to table users 
drop cascades to extension pg_stat_statements 
2015-08-10T02:55:05Z app[postgres.3977]: [GREEN] statement: CREATE SCHEMA public 
2015-08-10T02:55:05Z app[postgres.3977]: [GREEN] statement: ALTER SCHEMA public OWNER TO uca46vrebkj2l9 
2015-08-10T02:56:02Z app[postgres.4009]: [GREEN] statement: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_stat_statements
```

Comment: Restoring pg backup and application timeouts are two different things entirely. You can put your application in maintenance mode and still restore pg backup, actually that how you should be doing.

Comment: If you access `AWS_FILE_URL` in browser directly does it start the file download ?

Comment: @abhishek77in yes it does

Comment: @abhishek77in I can see how those are two separate things and yet the heroku docs states "Although this log is emitted from postgres, the cause for the error has nothing to do with the database itself. Your application happened to crash while connected to postgres, and did not clean up its connection to the database. Postgres noticed that the client (your application) disappeared without ending the connection properly, and logged a message saying so."  I'm really confused, as the log from my app doesn't say anything.  could you provide a bit more detail about maintenance mode?

Comment: interesting. Try restoring the app after doing the following two commands:
 `heroku maintenance:on` and `heroku ps:scale web=0 worker=0`. Generally I don't try to do pg restore on a live site.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/maintenance-mode

Comment: Please note you will have to reverse run these commands when you are done   with backup restore.

Comment: @abhishek77in thanks for the advice but unfortunately turning maintenance mode on did not work.  exact same results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86567/discussion-between-abhishek77in-and-allenwlee).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK this is hard for me to post because I feel so stupid, but the direct solution to my problem was that I didn't make my link public on Amazon S3.  That's why I was getting a 403 error.

The potential confusion is that you can use the non-public-link, which is a long string of encoded characters. But it uses a cached URL.  Because the cache is temporary, the cache was thrown away before my restore process could finish.

So the answer is to make the Amazon S3 link public, and then to use the public link, e.g.: `https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/your_bucket_name/your_file_name.dump`.

Then: `heroku pg:backups restore 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/your_bucket_name/your_file_name.dump' HEROKU_DATABASE_URL`.

Having said that, concurrent to this problem I believe there still is a 'deadlocking' issue related to `AccessExclusiveLock` that I need to resolve separately, that was making the pg_restore take long enough for the cache to timeout, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: Does anyone have solutions to this problem that don't involve making the link public? Making the link of a database dump containing customer data public is far from ideal from a security perspective.