# Error on pg_restore, possibly related to AccessExclusiveLock

Tags: postgresql, heroku

Postgres 9.4.1, Ruby 2.2, Rails 4.2

Basically, my pg_restore is failing. I've done a lot of work to isolate it down this far (ruling out application, heroku, connection). This is way beyond my scope of knowledge of Postgres, and I don't even know where to go next.  I can only paste the relevant log file and hope you see something.  For a full background of how this came about, please look at my [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909947/heroku-pgbackups-restore-fail-due-apparently-to-rails-application-timeout).  However, based on a discussion with user [abhishek77in](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/753705/abhishek77in) we think we've isolated it to Postgres, and it might possibly be related to this section of the log (although we are not sure):

```
Detail: Process 3977 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 35169 of database 16385. 
Query: DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE 
2015-08-10T02:55:05Z app[postgres.3977]: [GREEN] process 3977 still waiting for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 35169 of database 16385 after 1000.367 ms
```

Here is the output from `heroku logs -t`:

```
015-08-10T02:55:04Z app[postgres.3977]: [GREEN] statement: DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE 
2015-08-10T02:55:05Z app[postgres.3675]: [GREEN] canceling autovacuum task 
2015-08-10T02:55:05Z app[postgres.3977]: [GREEN] sending cancel to blocking autovacuum PID 3675 
Detail: Process 3977 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 35169 of database 16385. 
Query: DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE 
2015-08-10T02:55:05Z app[postgres.3977]: [GREEN] process 3977 still waiting for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 35169 of database 16385 after 1000.367 ms 
Detail: Process holding the lock: 3675. Wait queue: 3977. 
Query: DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE 
2015-08-10T02:55:05Z app[postgres.3977]: [GREEN] process 3977 acquired AccessExclusiveLock on relation 35169 of database 16385 after 1000.779 ms 
Query: DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE 
2015-08-10T02:55:05Z app[postgres.3977]: [GREEN] drop cascades to 97 other objects 
Detail: drop cascades to extension hstore 
drop cascades to type daily_box_input 
//<--84 tables, materialized views and views redacted for brevity-->// 
drop cascades to table users 
drop cascades to extension pg_stat_statements 
2015-08-10T02:55:05Z app[postgres.3977]: [GREEN] statement: CREATE SCHEMA public 
2015-08-10T02:55:05Z app[postgres.3977]: [GREEN] statement: ALTER SCHEMA public OWNER TO uca46vrebkj2l9 
2015-08-10T02:54:33+00:00 app[heroku-postgres]: source=HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GREEN sample#current_transaction=368590 sample#db_size=4203753236bytes sample#tables=83 sample#active-connections=3 sample#waiting-connections=0 sample#index-cache-hit-rate=0 sample#table-cache-hit-rate=0.66674 sample#load-avg-1m=0.45 sample#load-avg-5m=0.71 sample#load-avg-15m=0.66 sample#read-iops=17.058 sample#write-iops=498.2 sample#memory-total=15405668kB sample#memory-free=283204kB sample#memory-cached=14065608kB sample#memory-postgres=477864kB 
2015-08-10T02:55:57.359270+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H80 desc="Maintenance mode" method=GET path="/" host=www.studiocomps.com request_id=e0d6bbd7-076f-4a56-93a1-2f80a45d28c4 fwd="74.86.158.110" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
2015-08-10T02:56:02Z app[postgres.4009]: [GREEN] statement: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_stat_statements 
2015-08-10T02:56:03.118589+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H80 desc="Maintenance mode" method=GET path="/" host=test.studiocomps.com request_id=25fbbab0-8005-454c-b432-0f9b91cd5a75 fwd="69.64.56.47" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
2015-08-10T02:55:43+00:00 app[heroku-postgres]: source=HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GREEN sample#current_transaction=368608 sample#db_size=9137940bytes sample#tables=0 sample#active-connections=2 sample#waiting-connections=0 sample#index-cache-hit-rate=0 sample#table-cache-hit-rate=0 sample#load-avg-1m=0.625 sample#load-avg-5m=0.7 sample#load-avg-15m=0.66 sample#read-iops=234.98 sample#write-iops=226.24 sample#memory-total=15405668kB sample#memory-free=4200392kB sample#memory-cached=10112136kB sample#memory-postgres=470496kB
```

Here is the tail end output from `heroku logs -t --ps postgres`:

```
2015-08-10T02:46:35Z app[postgres.2427]: [GREEN] duration: 3538.409 ms statement: COPY flows (id, created_at, updated_at, medium_id, value_subunit, timing_id, ultimate_ratio_id, sheet_id, company_id, value_to_date_subunit, period_start, period_end, currency_code, local_title, kind_id, theaters, screens, flowable_id, flowable_type) FROM stdin;
2015-08-10T02:47:15Z app[postgres.11]: [GREEN] checkpoint starting: xlog 
2015-08-10T02:47:53Z app[postgres.11]: [GREEN] checkpoint complete: wrote 14930 buffers (47.8%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 55 recycled; write=30.562 s, sync=7.386 s, total=38.138 s; sync files=219, longest=5.843 s, average=0.033 s 
2015-08-10T02:47:57Z app[postgres.2829]: [GREEN] statement: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_stat_statements 
2015-08-10T02:48:13Z app[postgres.11]: [GREEN] checkpoint starting: xlog 
2015-08-10T02:48:42Z app[postgres.11]: [GREEN] checkpoint complete: wrote 3766 buffers (12.1%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 38 recycled; write=26.669 s, sync=1.943 s, total=28.658 s; sync files=36, longest=1.118 s, average=0.053 s 
2015-08-10T02:49:11Z app[postgres.11]: [GREEN] checkpoint starting: xlog 
2015-08-10T02:49:25Z app[postgres.11]: [GREEN] checkpoint complete: wrote 80 buffers (0.3%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 26 recycled; write=2.021 s, sync=11.500 s, total=13.529 s; sync files=3, longest=6.301 s, average=3.833 s 
2015-08-10T02:50:15Z app[postgres.11]: [GREEN] checkpoint starting: xlog 
2015-08-10T02:50:20Z app[postgres.11]: [GREEN] checkpoint complete: wrote 81 buffers (0.3%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 38 recycled; write=1.586 s, sync=3.825 s, total=5.477 s; sync files=2, longest=3.823 s, average=1.912 s 
2015-08-10T02:51:08Z app[postgres.2427]: [GREEN] canceling statement due to user request 
Query: COPY rankings (id, person_id, max, min, current, date, period_years_min_max, created_at, updated_at) FROM stdin; 
2015-08-10T02:51:08Z app[postgres.2427]: [GREEN] could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer 
2015-08-10T02:51:08Z app[postgres.2427]: [GREEN] incomplete message from client 
2015-08-10T02:51:27Z app[postgres.11]: [GREEN] checkpoint starting: xlog 
2015-08-10T02:54:17Z app[postgres.11]: [GREEN] checkpoint complete: wrote 2098 buffers (6.7%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 58 recycled; write=169.538 s, sync=0.952 s, total=170.500 s; sync files=11, longest=0.887 s, average=0.086 s 
2015-08-10T02:55:04Z app[postgres.3977]: [GREEN] statement: DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE 
2015-08-10T02:55:05Z app[postgres.3675]: [GREEN] canceling autovacuum task 
2015-08-10T02:55:05Z app[postgres.3977]: [GREEN] sending cancel to blocking autovacuum PID 3675 
Detail: Process 3977 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 35169 of database 16385. 
Query: DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE 
2015-08-10T02:55:05Z app[postgres.3977]: [GREEN] process 3977 still waiting for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 35169 of database 16385 after 1000.367 ms 
Detail: Process holding the lock: 3675. Wait queue: 3977. 
Query: DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE 
2015-08-10T02:55:05Z app[postgres.3977]: [GREEN] process 3977 acquired AccessExclusiveLock on relation 35169 of database 16385 after 1000.779 ms 
Query: DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE 
2015-08-10T02:55:05Z app[postgres.3977]: [GREEN] drop cascades to 97 other objects 
Detail: drop cascades to extension hstore 
drop cascades to type daily_box_input 
//<--84 tables, materialized views and views redacted for brevity-->// 
drop cascades to table users 
drop cascades to extension pg_stat_statements 
2015-08-10T02:55:05Z app[postgres.3977]: [GREEN] statement: CREATE SCHEMA public 
2015-08-10T02:55:05Z app[postgres.3977]: [GREEN] statement: ALTER SCHEMA public OWNER TO uca46vrebkj2l9 
2015-08-10T02:56:02Z app[postgres.4009]: [GREEN] statement: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_stat_statements
```

Comment: Did you try asking same to Heroku support ? They might know better or if nothing show interest in your case.

Comment: yes i've opened a ticket in heroku and will post their response if it's helpful

Comment: `Detail: Process 3977 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 35169 of database 16385.` looks like there is a connected session to your database/schema/table. 2) I see: it is an autovacuum task.